Problem with generating tickets for event
I am trying to move a PHP website from one host (Avlux, which is shutting down) to another (DreamHost). I am having problems with code that generates event tickets. At this point, I am running the system in WampServer using Visual Studio Code to edit the programs.
This is the html code for the link to "Print" the ticket:
href="/tickets/tickets/<?=$o->id?>/?access_token=<?=$o->access_token()?>"

And this is the function:
public function access_token() {
   return base64_encode($this->id + 'ClearSight Studio');
}    

The problem:
On the old host, the ticket is generated.  base64_encode creates a set of characters such as: NjA4NTQ and prints a ticket.  On the new host, the hyperlink is not created and the program ends.
Question:  What does the question mark in "/?access_token" mean?
What I have tried:
I've tried isolating the code following tickets/tickets and running it standalone, but I can't seem to do that again without generating an error that seems to mess up the entire program in Visual Studio Code.
$o->id is an integer.  When I was able to run the function, access_token standalone, it could not concatenate an integer with a string. So I converted it to a string, $str_id, and replaced id?> with 

As for the question mark, have a look at the URL syntax. The question mark precedes the optional query component. Please edit your question to correct the code segments, as it is they make little sense.

the question mark in an URL makes the rest a parameter: my.php?param1=valueA&param2=valueB .. you can access the "values" in my.php via $_GET['param1']

Have you checked the error log on the server? By any chance did your change of host also involve moving to a newer version of php?

Yes it is a newer version of PHP: 8.0

Thanks. Ok so the change of PHP version is the reason for the difference in how your code behaves, not the change of host!

@Penny Hey Penny, welcome to Stack Overflow. This can be a rough place and i feel kinda sorry that your first contact was so bad. But this isn't simply a message board where others help you fix your problems. You need to show some effort to find a solution yourself. So naturally, for beginners, Stack Overflow is a harsh place. This place expects you to read tutorials and google answers before asking questions.

Thank you.  I feel like I went as far as I could before asking the question.  Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to do what you asked and close the question.

this code:
base64_encode($this->id + 'ClearSight Studio');

results in an error:

PHP Warning: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in php shell

instead, to concatenate a string with an integer, write:
base64_encode($this->id . 'ClearSight Studio');

It seems you were unable to see the error message. In your php.ini, set:
display_errors = On

... to see warnings and errors live during development. Make sure to remove this setting for production.

I'm not out of the woods yet, but your suggestion for the change to the function enabled the link to work.  The error display was already turned on -I am a getting stack trace.  I am very frustrated with the stack overflow site.  The rules for including code are baffling.  They seem to be inconsistent.

@Penny no they are not inconsistent. You must include code, but only as much as necessary to illustrate a single problem. We are not here to fix 200 LoC for you.

@Penny if this code helped you, please consider to accept this answer and / or upvote it.

I'm not trying to show 200 lines of code, but when I tried to edit my post, I couldn't get one line of code to post.  I even tried to copy/paste code I had originally posted, and copying that seemed to mess up the original.   So I just canceled it. But yes, I will accept the answer, because the link did work.  Thank you.

This
href="/tickets/tickets/<?=$o->id?>/?access_token=<?=$o->

Means a href which includes /tickets/tickets/, followed by whatever value (presumably numeric) $o->id has, followed by /?, ending the effective part of the URL which specifies where to send the request and the ? here states that the query string comes, where you will have key=value pairs, separated by & ampersands. So, access_token is part of the query string and represents a GET parameter (which you will be able to reach via $_GET['access_token']) in your PHP code) and the value of this would be whatever you describe, presumably $o->access_token or something of the like. Your code is broken for not having a proper enclosing for your <? which is a syntax to hand over the initiative to PHP to type in something into the template, as PHP is a templating language. So you will need to figure out what $o is and fix the code above to something like
href="/tickets/tickets/<?=$o->id?>/?access_token=<?=$o->access_token?>


dunno, wasn't me. But your answer does not solve the issue with the code. Maybe thats why?

Also maybe because <?= is not "old syntax" but standard.

Also "php is a templating language" lol. Which year is it? 1996?

@Kaii thanks for pointing out that <?= is standard. I still think it's old syntax and I personally do not use it, but adjusted the answer accordingly. As about PHP being a template language, that's true now too, as you can echo via PHP into HTML. Nevertheless, thanks for the pointers of what you considered subpar.

Sorry, the code that ended up in my post got truncated.  It is exactly as suggested above:

which was: href="/tickets/tickets/id?>/?access_token=access_token?>

Thank you, Lajos.  This was helpful.  I'm pretty new to PHP.
